# my done button somehow went to a blank page and delete won't work unless I refresh -ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, button

I am playing around with a todo list I learned online.  Trying to add ajax into it. 
Works well when I try to add an item.  When an item is added there's a button says 'Mark as done' so I can click on it and then there will be a 'Delete' button which is used to delete the item from the list and database.

Adding with ajax works fine but after adding, if I click on 'Mark as done' button, the page goes to the url of `done-ajax.php?as=done&item=110`
where 110 is just the id of the item in database.
I have to go back to the index page.  And when I go back to index page the item will be marked done already because the 'Mark as done' worked but somehow would go to the url instead of staying in the index page.

This is one of the problems found that I have no idea where to look for the result.

Another problem is if I add the item and refresh the page then clicked 'Mark as done' it wouldn't go to the url instead the ajax works and a 'delete' button would show up but some how the delete button wouldn't work.  I have to refresh the page in order for the 'delete' button to work with ajax.
I checked the attributes and looked around the codes but couldn't seem to find where is causing the problem.

my index codes are as below

```
<div class="list">
<h1 class="header">ET's To do lists.</h1>

<?php if(!empty($items)): ?>
<ul class="items">
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
    <li>
                    <span class="item<?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : '' ?>">
                        <?php echo $item['todoText']; ?>
                    </span>
        <?php if($item['done']): ?>
        <a href="delete-ajax.php?as=delete&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="delete-button">Delete Task</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!$item['done']): ?>
        <a href="done-ajax.php?as=done&item=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="done-button">Mark as done</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="empty">You haven't added any items yet.</p>
<ul class="items"></ul>
<?php endif ?>

<form class="item-add" action="add.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="todoText" placeholder="Type a new item here." class="input" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit">
</form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

my ajax.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Action when submit is clicked
$(".submit").click(function(e){
var todoText = $("input[name='todoText']").val();
e.preventDefault();

//Ajax for adding todoText
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "add-ajax.php",
data: {todoText: todoText},
dataType: "json"
})
.done(function(data){
$('p.empty').empty();
$('input.input').val('');
$('ul.items').append('<li>'+todoText+' '+
    '<a href="done-ajax.php?as=done&item=' + data.id +
                '" class="done-button">Mark as Done</a></li>');
})
});

//Action when done button is clicked
$(".done-button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

//making sure only work with the current element
var $clicked = $(this);

//get the href attribute value and parse it to get the item # which is the item's id
var attrValue = $clicked.attr('href');
var parseAttrValue = attrValue.split('&');
var parseItem = parseAttrValue[1].split('=');
var item = parseItem[1];

//Ajax for Mark as Done Button
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
data:{as: 'done', item: item},
url: "done-ajax.php"
})
.done(function(){
$clicked.prev().addClass('done');
$clicked.removeClass('done-button').empty();
$clicked.addClass('delete-button').text('Delete Task');
$clicked.removeAttr('href');
$clicked.attr('href','delete-ajax.php?as=delete&item='+item);
});
});

//Action when delete button is clicked
$(".delete-button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

//making sure only work with the current element
var $clicked = $(this);

//get the href attribute value and parse it to get the item # which is the item's id
var attrValue = $clicked.attr('href');
var parseAttrValue = attrValue.split('&');
var parseItem = parseAttrValue[1].split('=');
var item = parseItem[1];

//Ajax for Mark as Done Button
$.ajax({
method: "GET",
data:{as: 'delete', item: item},
url: "delete-ajax.php"
})
.done(function(){
$clicked.closest('li').remove();
$clicked.remove();
});
});
});

my done-ajax.php file


<?php

require_once 'app/init.php';

if (isset($_GET['as'], $_GET['item']))
{
    $as = $_GET['as'];
    $item = $_GET['item'];

    switch ($as) {
        case 'done':
            $doneQuery = $db->prepare("
UPDATE phptodolist_items
SET done = 1
WHERE id = :item
AND user = :user
");
break;
}
}


my delete.php file

<?php

require_once 'app/init.php';

if (isset($_GET['as'], $_GET['item']))
{
    $as = $_GET['as'];
    $item = $_GET['item'];

    switch ($as) {
        case 'delete':

            $doneQuery = $db->prepare("
DELETE FROM phptodolist_items
WHERE id = :item
AND user = :user
");
break;
}
}
```

(By the way, thanks to few that helped out with the ajax earlier)
Thanks a lot to everyone in advance :D

Comment: as far as i can understand, your "done" button does not exist on page load, correct? 
So, in your js, in `$(".done-button")`, it is impossible for jquery to fire this click event, because there s no such class on page load. Take a look (and read) on jquery's `.live()`. It will help you solve your problem

Comment: @andrew `live()` is deprecated, you need `on()`.

Comment: @jeroen you are correct, my bad habits die hard as it seems

Comment: ah! Thanks a lot! I was trying to look again and do figured when I click delete my `as` value should be `delete` but instead it's `done` and I have no idea why :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your event handlers when the page opens / the DOM is ready, on `$(document).ready()`. Then you add new items using ajax but the links in these items will not have your event handlers bound to them.

You can use event delegation to make sure that the events are also automatically bound to newly added items.

You can do that changing:

```
$(".delete-button").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
...
```

to something like:

```
$(".list").on('click', '.delete-button', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

where the `$(".list")` can be any element that contains the newly added elements and that is on the page when this code executes.

This applies to all event handlers that you want to bind to elements that are not yet on the page when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks thanks a lot~ really didn't know this. I guess this is used a lot for ajax?

Comment: @Dora Yes, this is the way to bind events to dynamically added elements. Note that there are also times when you need to bind things manually in your success handler, like datapickers, etc.

Comment: somehow I added this to my submit too (which is the add) but now it's refreshing the page instead of doing ajax O.o any ideas?

Comment: @Dora Are you sure the button / form is a child element of the containing element that you used? And you should really bind to the form submit event instead of the button press in case it gets submitted using the enter key.

Comment: now I left the submit to original code which is `$('.submit').click(function(e){...` I changed the done / delete to `$('li').on('click', '.done-button', function(e){...` and `$('li').on('click', '.delete-button', function(e){` but this way, after adding and if I click on the done button it goes to the blank page with the get url again.  if I change the submit code to `$('input').on('click', '.submit', function(e){....` then each time when I add item, the page actually refreshes

Comment: what do you mean by bind the form submit event?

Comment: @Dora Check my answer, the element you bind to **must** be on the page on page load. The `li` items are not and there is no parent element `input` for the `.submit` element. When in doubt, just use `$('body').on(...)`.

Comment: `$('form.item-add').on('submit', function() {});`